# "-map t" vs "-map 0:t" vs "-tcodec copy"?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

in order to copy all attachments from input file to output file... is there any difference between:

> -map t / -map 0:t
>
> &
>
> -tcodec copy

which of those should be used? and also a sub-question if I may ask: when doing 2 pass encode with ffmpeg + x265 and I have 1 batch per each pass, should I use map/codec copy in both of them or just in the 2nd pass/batch? (1st pass is NUL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-tcodec copy** doesnt exist (definitely not in pipe with latest (20180506-0736f32-win64-static) ffmpeg.exe and x265.exe). also its not so effective to move attachments into each pass til reaching the final output. in such case mkvmerge.exe wins over ffmpeg.exe

```
mkvmerge.exe -o "X:\done.mkv" "K:\encoded.mkv" -A -D -S -B -T --no-chapters --no-global-tags "O:\source.mkv" "K:\audio.flac"
```

Comment: The alias doesn't exist. You can copy attachments using `-c:t copy`. And you don't need to add attachments except when creating the final output.

Answer (score 1):

`-map t` will only select streams from the first input, so it is equivalent to `-map 0:t`. The latter form should be preferred, since it explicitly defines the input file.

`-c:t copy` (alias -tcodec isn't defined) sets the codec operation for any mapped attachment streams. If no such streams are explicitly mapped, then the option has no effect. Particularly, it does not select such streams for output in the absence of mapping.

Comment: so I should use both switches? `ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -map 0:t -tcodec copy video1.mkv`

Comment: Yes, the map selects streams for output; tcodec sets codec mode.